# How do I fix my Python program

Tags: python, calendar

```
import datetime

import time
import locale

now = datetime.datetime.now()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')

geboortejaar = input("Wanneer ben je geboren? (jaar)")

leeftijd = 2017 - int(geboortejaar)

maand = int(input("En in welke maand? (getal)"))

dag = int(input("En op welke dag? (getal)"))

Weekdag = time.strftime("%d").upper()

Maand = time.strftime("%m").upper()

if maand >= Maand and dag >= Weekdag:
    print("Je bent dan " + str(leeftijd - 1) + " jaar oud en leeft al ongeveer " + str((leeftijd - 1) * 365) + " dagen!" )
else:
    print("Je bent dan " + str(leeftijd) + " jaar oud en leeft al ongeveer " + str(leeftijd * 365) + " dagen!")
```

I live in the Netherlands and I wanted to make a Program that tells you how old you are without having to change some things everyday but by taking calendar info. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: first you need to fix indentation

Comment: Seen `datetime.today()`?

Comment: This is my error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 8, in <module> locale.Error: unsupported locale setting –

Comment: Please, improve the readability of your post. First of all, if you have an error with a specific instruction, is not necessary to post the whole code. Secondly, if you have an error message, it is very relevant to include it in the post as well. Lastly, do not post your code and hope for someone to come and solve your problem. Instead, introduce your problematic and explain what you tried so far, and maybe which hypothesis you have

Comment: Sorry, but this is the first time I post something. I started like a month a go and most of the time my teacher helped me so I kinda don't know how t ask something on a forum. My excuses!

Answer (score 1):

this is a code in python:

```
from datetime import date

anio, month , day = map( int , raw_input().split())
birthday = date( anio, month, day)
now = date.today()
thetime = now - birthday
print("how old are you? the time is: ")
print("you have %s years" % (thetime.days/365))
print("you have %s days" % (thetime.days ) )
```

you can improve that by using dictionary to map string( representing a month ) to int( number of month ) to create a `birthday` variable more readible.